# Java find best way to solve checking Continuous numbers [Algorithm]

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, data-structures

I try to find elegant way to solve one issue.

```
Issue : Check few numbers continuity.

Value : Start number, End Number (Each Number Group)
```

There is group for example.

```
First Group : Start 1, End 90
Second Group : Start 91, End 180
Third Group : Start 181, End 225
Forth Group : Start 226, End 310
Fifth Group : Start 311, End 360
```

As you can check above lists, group is connecting

```
First Group End : 90 , Second Group Start 91.
Second Group End : 180, Third Group Start 181.
```

So all group numbers are connected together.

```
Then results is correct, Status show correct

But if there is disconnecting point, status should be not correct.
```

Example for Not Correct.

```
First Group : Start 1, End 90
Second Group : Start 94, End 180
Third Group : Start 181, End 225  

First Group End 90, Second Group Start 94. So it's not continuous numbers.
```

I can put ArrayLists and check one by one,
but I want to know anyone has elegant solution to make dynamic logic?

My solution could be.

```
ArrayList<Integer> ArrStartRawData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> ArrEndRawData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrStartRawData.add(Group[0].start);
ArrEndRawData.add(Group[0].end);
ArrStartRawData.add(Group[1].start);
ArrEndRawData.add(Group[1].end);
ArrStartRawData.add(Group[2].start);
ArrEndRawData.add(Group[2].end);

String status = "";
for(int z=0; z < ArrEndRawData.size() ; z++){
    Integer num = ArrEndRawData.get(z);
    if(z != ArrEndRawData.size()-1) {
        if((ArrStartRawData.get(z+1)-ArrEndRawData.get(z)) == 1) {
            status = "Correct";
        } else {
            status = "Not Correct";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has better idea to make dynamic code?

Thanks

Comment: may input be as the following ? First Group : Start 1, End 90
Second Group : Start 80, End 180

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi Possible but results will be Not Correct ! Because it has to be continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one can also do the job.

```
        String status = "Not Correct";
        int z = ArrStartRawData.size()-1;
        while (--z>=0 && ArrStartRawData.get(z+1) == ArrEndRawData.get(z)+1);            
        if (z < 0) status = "Correct";
```

Answer (score 0):

That could work. You could also use the initial Arrays they are in for the same functionality. Also if you start on z = 1, you could remove the if statement and only check for false statements...

But since I'm not sure what your starting with here's this... Just what you had, but not as complex. Sorry that's the only way from what I understand.

```
status = "Correct";
for(int z=1; z < ArrEndRawData.size() ; z++){
    if((ArrStartRawData.get(z) - ArrEndRawData.get(z-1)) != 1) {
        status = "Not Correct";
        break;
    }
}
```

Also for fun and dynamic I'd add something to ensure your End has as many as the Start.